# AJAX загрузка контента с другой страницы

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Не загружает контент другой страницы. Подскажите в чем причина? выводит FIND = undefined.

Вот функция:

```
function replaceMap() {
    var data = {
        country:$("#country").val(),
        region:$("#region").val(),
        city:$("#city").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: getContextPath()+"/ajax/location",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
            var findHTML = $(html).find("#location").html();
            alert("FIND = "+findHTML);
            $("#location").html(findHTML);
        }
    });
}
```

вот контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class CtrAjax {

    @Autowired private DAOCountry countryDAO;
    @Autowired private DAORegion regionDAO;
    @Autowired private DAOCity cityDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value="/ajax/location", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView viewLocation(
            @RequestParam(value = "country", required = false) String country,
            @RequestParam(value = "region", required = false) String region,
            @RequestParam(value = "city", required = false) String city
    ) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Ajax_Location");

        Address address = new Address();
        if (country!=null) address.setCountry(countryDAO.get(country));
        if (region!=null) address.setRegion(regionDAO.get(region));
        if (city!=null) address.setCity(cityDAO.get(city));
        model.addObject("address", address);

        model.addObject("list_country", countryDAO.getAll());
        if (country!=null) model.addObject("list_region", regionDAO.getAll(address.getCountry()));
        if (country!=null && region!=null) model.addObject("list_city", cityDAO.getAll(address.getRegion()));

        return model;
    }

}
```

вот HTML:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>AJAX Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="location">
            <form:select path="address.country">
                <option selected disabled hidden>Страна</option>
                <form:options items="${list_country}"/>
            </form:select>
            <form:select path="address.region">
                <option selected disabled hidden>Регион</option>
                <form:options items="${list_region}"/>
            </form:select>
            <form:select path="address.city">
                <option selected disabled hidden>Город</option>
                <form:options items="${list_city}"/>
            </form:select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#country").change(function() {replaceMap();});
                $("#region").change(function() {replaceMap();});
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Посмотрите что тут `$(html)`. `jQuery` не умеет такое нормально парсить (по крайней мере мне не удавалось спарсить целый `html`).

Comment: @Tsyklop уже сделал. Скорей всего в этом дело. В консоль выводит весь html. Но не парсит

Answer (score 0):

смог реализовать, но не уверен что правильно:

```
function replaceMap() {
    var data = {
        country:$("#country").val(),
        region:$("#region").val(),
        city:$("#city").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: getContextPath()+"/ajax/location",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(html) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = html;
            var textHTML = $(div).find('#location').html();
            $("#location").html(textHTML);
        }
    });
}
```